# Make sure that one javascript gets run before another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two javascript-files. That currently both get loaded in the header

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://filer.jungrelations.com/beaussometumblr/js/main.js">
        <script src="http://filer.jungrelations.com/beaussometumblr/js/vendor/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

main.js does some manipulation to the order in the DOM. Applies masonry, an javascript library that positions elements absolutely based on their order in the DOM. I initiate it using the data-masonry-object-method:

```
data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 196,  "itemSelector": "section", "gutter": 8, "transitionDuration": 0 }'
```

Because masonry cares about the order of the html-nodes, It's important that main.js is run before masonry.js. This is what main.js looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.stamp1').remove();
});
```

Comment: why is your main.js in a link element?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/779320

Comment: `link rel="stylesheet"` means the browser will treat it as CSS, not as Javascript. You need them both to be `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you manually activate masonry in your main.js, after you did the DOM manipulation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stamp1').remove(); 


    $('#container').masonry({
       columnWidth: 196,
       itemSelector: 'section',
       gutter: 8, 
       transitionDuration: 0
    });

});
```

You'll also have to remove the data-masonry-options attribute from your container.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pull in the second script file in your first:

`$.getScript('second-file.js');`

Thus your main.js looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.stamp1').remove();            //do whatever you need to do
   $.getScript('second-file.js');    //load the second script
});
```